# Prolog GNU - Univ operator? Explanation of it

Tags: prolog, operator-keyword, backtracking, meta-predicate

So the univ operator. I don't exactly understand it.

For example this:

```
foo(PredList,[H|_]) :- bar(PredList,H).
foo(PredList,[_|T]) :- foo(PredList,T),!.

bar([H|_],Item) :- G =.. [H,Item],G.
bar([_|T],Item) :- bar(T,Item).
```

What is this doing? This looks to see if another predicate is true. I don't understand what the ".." does.

How would you rewrite this without the univ operator?

Comment: +1 for asking how to rewrite without univ. Btw, there are ISO predicates functor/3 and arg/3 which might do the job in some cases, and should be preferred, but I'm not sure they can always be used.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Univ (`=..`) breaks up a term into a list of constituents, or constructs a term from such a list. Try:

```
?- f(x,y) =.. L.
L = [f, x, y].

?- f(x,y,z) =.. [f|Args].
Args = [x, y, z].

?- Term =.. [g,x,y].
Term = g(x, y).
```

`bar` seems to call each predicate in `PredList` on `Item`, with `foo` backtracking over the `Item`s. (Using a variable as a predicate is not portable; the `call` predicate should be preferred.)

**Edit**: Kaarel is right, univ can be replaced by `functor/3` and `arg/3`, as follows:

```
bar([H|_],Item) :-
    functor(Goal,H,1),   % unifies Goal with H(_)
    arg(1,Goal,Item),    % unifies first argument of Goal with Item
    call(Goal).          % use this for portability
```

Comment: Good answer.  Just for clarification: The univ operator unifies the term on the left with the list on the right, so that the head of the list is the functor, and the tail of the list are the arguments.

Comment: @larsmans: You are forcing `H` to be an atom. So you are preventing partial application! See @Cookie Monster's solution.

Answer (score 3):

The most appropriate rewrite in my opinion would be:

```
 bar( [H|_], Item ) :- call(H, Item).
```

`call/n` are not yet part of the ISO core standard, but they might become in the near future (*). A lot of Prolog systems already support them.

There is one reason why `call/n` should be preferred over simple `(=..)/2` and `functor/3` + `arg/3` solutions. The `call/n` solution is capable to handle closures (**).

With the simple `(=..)/2` and `functor/3` + `arg/3` solution one can invoke `bar/2` only with atoms in the first list argument. For example:

```
 p1(1).
 p2(2).
 ?- bar( [p1, p2], 1 ).
 Yes
 ?- bar( [p1, p2], 2 ).
 Yes
 ?- bar( [p1, p2], 3 ).
 No
```

With closures we are not restricted to atoms, and we might save some coding effort. For example we can do the following directly:

```
 ?- bar( [=(1), =(2)], 1 ).
 Yes
 ?- bar( [=(1), =(2)], 2 ).
 Yes
 ?- bar( [=(1), =(2)], 3 ).
 No
```

Best Regards

(*)
Draft Technical Corrigendum 2
http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/dtc2#call

(**)
Who Invented It?: `call/n` Predicates
http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/naish.html

Comment: About "Who invented it": The actual first written source I am aware of is the _1984 Draft Proposed Standard for Prolog Evaluable Predicates_ by Richard O'Keefe which was first publicly announced 1984-07-25. You find a precursor restricted to some not fully specified kind of lambdas but **not permitting partial application** in Mycroft, O'Keefe _A polymorphic type system for Prolog_, AI Journal, August 1984.

Comment: I guess this is in accordance with the statement "(1) Alan Mycroft and I invented call/N together. No-one else was involved." from ROK found in the second reference?

Comment: Somehow. But not entirely. There are other statements suggesting that `call/N` was already invented in that paper.

Comment: Well it must be this paper and not the draft, since the draft is by ROK and the paper is by Mycroft & ROK, and ROK says in the news exchange (my second reference marked (**)) Mycroft AND ROK invented it.

Comment: That is what common reasoning in the absence of sources suggests. But it is no substitute reading the paper.  [This is what is written there.](https://lists.iai.uni-bonn.de/pipermail/swi-prolog/2010/004642.html)

Comment: Yeah I didn't verify the sources. But anyway since call/n is inspired by LISP funcall (ROK admits that), its more a joke to say it has been invented then and then for Prolog.

Comment: Is it? What is the funcall analogon to call(=(1),Y)?

Comment: Well, it seems that it is not: I found: X3J13 voted in June 1988 (FUNCTION-TYPE)   to allow the fn to be only of type symbol or function; a lambda-expression is no longer acceptable as a functional argument. One must use the function special form or the abbreviation #' before a lambda-expression that appears as an explicit argument form.
Compatibility note: The Common Lisp function funcall corresponds roughly to the Interlisp primitive apply*. http://www.ida.liu.se/imported/cltl/clm/node81.html

Comment: So partial application is not present. And there are still [proposals to it](http://blarneyfellow.wordpress.com/2009/03/05/announcing-cl-op-a-partial-application-library-for-cl/). So this step from apply in the AI paper to call/N is the real thing!

Comment: I cannot judge, I don't have the paper at hand. But putting too much curry in your meal can make it too spicy and less balanced. Pitty ROKs proposal is incomplete, no ^/n. BTW: In this news exchange there is also a mention of a type for call/n: http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/projects/ALP/newsletter/archive_93_96/net/typing/call.html