# Element handling issue in Prolog, but not in a regular list?

Tags: list, prolog, element, member

I'm trying to write an element handling function in Prolog. It's almost the same as the prolog predicate member/2 but it must do the job in a different way. For being specific; I must say the member/2 predicate function is this:

```
member(X, [X|_]).
member(X, [_|Tail]) :-
   member(X,Tail).
```

When you give a query for example: `member(X, [1,2,3])`.

It gives you `X = 1; X = 2; X = 3;` in this order for all redo's. I want an element function almost the same. I want the same result with the member function when I give a query like this:

```
element(X, (1,2,3)).
```

The difference is just parenthesis instead of bracekts like these : []
In order to do this I tried that:

```
element(X, (X,_)).
element(X, (_,Tail)) :-
   element(X,Tail).
```

Which is exactly the same as member/2 predicate function implementation. But this doesn't work because it doesn't giving the last element which is `X=3.`
So I added one more fact that is:

```
element(X, X).
```

But this doesn't work either because (obviously) it is giving unnecessary answer with real elements like these:

```
X=(1,2,3)
X=(2,3)
```

How can I handle this?

Comment: your `member/2` code is off: it should read `[_|Tail]`, not `[_,Tail]`

Comment: Yes I wrote it wrong here sorry, I'm making it correct now. By the way I'm using it in the program in the right way as you said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems that a cut can solve your problem:

```
element(X, (X, _)).
element(X, (_, Tail)) :-
    !, element(X, Tail).
element(X, X).
```

test:

```
?- element(X, (1,2,3)).
X = 1 ;
X = 2 ;
X = 3.

?- element(2, (1,2,3,2)).
true ;
true.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm so embarrased that I couldn't see this. I tried to use a cut but because I'm very new to prolog I couldn't place it properly where it's necessary. I'm trying to figure out how prolog works for different situations by the trace option while testing but I couldn't really understand what cut (!) operator does. Can anybody explain it in a proper way? Thanks a lot for the answer again.

Comment: I found an explanation like this and it looks good; I could understand now some more but for usage I must get used to it: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut_(logic_programming).

Answer (score 1):

Terms like `(1,2,3)` in Prolog have commas as their primary functor.  Probably you want to use operator [univ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4129484/prolog-gnu-univ-operator-explanation-of-it), denoted by infix `=..`, or its close relations `functor/3` and `arg/3` to pick apart these tuples.